# Is there a ready-made inotify program to monitor changes on a directory?

Tags: linux, security, monitoring

I am trying to understand how inotify works and it seems that you need to program stuff in C for it to work.

Since I don't know C, I was wondering if there is a program or script already made to monitor a single directory.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions. Regards

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. Do you think it's reliable/trustworthy?
You can put it up as an answer if you wish. Thanks a lot

Comment: It's been around for quite some time, and is widely used. You can make whatever assumptions you want from that.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/418151/59925

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron). Incron uses the inotify kernel hooks to let you run cron-like commands when certain specified events happen on the filesystem.